# C# Why use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture for such a simple task

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

Ok i am going through Saplo Api C# project. It stump me when i saw these code:

```
public class Helper
{
    private static int _currentId;
    public static int GetCurrentId()
    {
        return _currentId;
    }
    public static int GetNextId()
    {
        return ++_currentId;
    }
}

[DataContract]
internal class RequestBase<T>
{
    public RequestBase()
    {
        ID = Helper.GetNextId().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public RequestBase(string method, T @params)
        : this()
    {
        Method = method;
        Parameters = @params;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string ID { get; private set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "params")]
    public T Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

So if you look at the constructor for RequestBase.... public RequestBase()! you will see Helper.GetNextId() this only return an int why bother using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture i dont understand why a simple ToString inst good enough to do the job or what, isnt this is just more overhead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to integers, there is *currently* no recognized, official culture that would affect how `Int32.ToString()` behaves.  It will always create an identical string.

However, that does not mean that a custom culture might not interpret the results differently.  Resharper and other code style tools typically recommend using a culture to maintain consistency.

It is worth noting, when travelling outside of integers, cultures absolutely make a difference.  For instance, in EN-US, commas are used for thousands separation and periods are used to represent the decimal point.  On the other hand, in EN-GB it's the opposite.  Keeping consistency between value types could certainly be viewed as a good habit.

That said, in this case, yes, providing CultureInfo for integers is probably unnecessary "overhead", unless you prefer to keep consistency in your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it doesn't seem necessary.  I know plugins like ReSharper and StyleCop will complain(show a warning) about an empty ToString() unless you tell them not to.  It's possible one of these plugins was used when writing this code.

Generally `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is used when converting dates and decimal/currency values.